# Image not loading when i go in the website

Tags: python, image, flask

When i go in the website, the image is not here, instead, it says "user_image" (i used a code in another question)

Python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import os

PEOPLE_FOLDER = os.path.join('templates', 'Image')

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = PEOPLE_FOLDER


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def show_index():
    full_filename = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'templates/Image/image.png')

    return render_template("render.html", user_image=full_filename)


app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=0)
```

html: (render.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="{{ user_image }}" alt="User Image">
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to connect on another computer, but the problem is still here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the path to your image is incorrect. You join `templates` and `Image` in `PEOPLE_FOLDER` resulting in `templates/Image`.

But then you do so again with `app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'templates/Image/image.png'` resulting in `templates/Image/templates/Image/image.png`.

Change `app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'templates/Image/image.png'` to `app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'image.png'`

However, I would recommend properly structuring your project first. Flask recommends the `templates` dir only be used for html files and the `static` dir be used for all assets used by the templates (images, styling, etc).

From Flask documentation:

> The static folder contains assets used by the templates, including CSS
> files, JavaScript files, and images. In the example, we have only one
> asset file, main.css
> The templates folder contains only templates. These have an .html
> extension. As we will see, they contain more than just regular HTML

Additional info on [structuring a flask project](https://python-adv-web-apps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/flask3.html#:%7E:text=Folder%20structure%20for%20a%20Flask%20app&text=That%20folder%20contains%20two%20folders,only%20one%20asset%20file%2C%20main.).